# SQL Query in arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, sql

I have a BUILDING.SHP and in the attribute table, it has several names and some of the attributes are "STOR" and "MULTIPLE-STOREY CAR PARK" like image below.

[image]

[image]

In my map, I don't want label the records that say "STOR" or that contain "STOR" like "STOR BARANG".

In my SQL Query, I have used (NAME NOT Like '%STOR%') however the MULTI-STOREY CAR PARK also disappeared.

Is there any other query that can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a LIKE statement will return any string containing the search terms - in this case "STOR". I believe you are looking to only filter out names that are specifically "STOR".

In that case simple using NAM <> 'STOR' should do the trick.

To exclude labels like "STOR BARANG" and "STOR" but still include "MULTIPLE STOREY CAR PARK," use NAM not like 'STOR%'.

Comment: i used the query (NAM NOT Like '%STOR%')because, if in the attributes  have features name like STOR KAYU, STOR BARANG or anything that have STOR in their name, i must not label it. i try to use the query NAM<>'STOR' but it only not label the 'STOR'.

Comment: DID you consider not like 'STOR%'

Comment: I already try(NAM NOT LIKE'STOR%')and its work..thank you so much..

Comment: @user If this answer solved your problem, please click the checkmark to mark it as "answered."